# 2D IIR filter design (x-axis width proportional to y-axis)

Tags: filter-design, 2d

I want to design a 2D IIR filter (that is, created line-by-line progressively, in this case from left-to-right).  What is the best way to go about this?

I would like the response to look something vaguely like this:

[image: diagram]

The actual shape in the x-axis (time) isn't important - what's important is that the response's width for the x-axis is proportional to the y-axis position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might be looking for a FIR filter (2d convolution)? If that's the case, you gave the answer yourself.

If you're actually looking for an IIR filter, then I'd like to ask for the desired order.

Comment: It's a tradeoff, really.  Past about 64th order I guess it'd be a bit silly. :p